# Supabase issue with using 'and' & 'or' filters for my table

Tags: postgresql, supabase

I have a React table & im trying to fetch data from my table where the employee count ONLY matches ranges between 1-10 OR 21-50.

```js
const { data, error } = await supabase
        .from<SupabaseData>('masterlist1')
        .select('*')
        .order('Lead ID', { ascending: true })
        .range(startIdx, endIdx)
        .or(`employees.gte.1,employees.lte.10`)
        .or(`employees.gte.21,employees.lte.50`)
```

This is not working, and the table on my front-end is still full of numbers out of these ranges.

I've tried many variants of the string, and other combinations

Comment: Welcome to the SO community. The community will help with your issues, but there are certain expectations on you. Please spend a few minuets to take the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and review [ask]. 
 Then update your question to include sample data, table definition (ddl scripts), the expected results of that data and what you have tried, all as text - **no images**; also adding a  [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/) is extremely useful. Further clearly describe what you are attempting and where you are having issues.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can combine `and` filters with `or` filters in Supabase. You can find this example [here](https://supabase.com/docs/reference/javascript/or?example=use-or-with-and) in the docs.

```js
const { data, error } = await supabase
  .from<SupabaseData>('masterlist1')
  .select('*')
  .order('Lead ID', { ascending: true })
  .range(startIdx, endIdx)
  .or('employees.gte.21,employees.lte.50,and(employees.gte.1,employees.lte.10)')
```